# how do i write test for the click event of this component?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

`<IssueTitle onClick={() => handleClick(issue.id)} data-testid="issue-title"> {issue.title} </IssueTitle>`

How can i test this click event using jest

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using **fireEvent** and **getByTestId**

```
const handleClick = jest.fn()

const { getByTestId } = render (<IssueTitle 
onClick={() => handleClick(1)} 
data-testid="issue-title"> {issue.title} 
</IssueTitle>)
    
fireEvent.click(getByTestId("issue-title"));
expect(handleClick).toBeCalledWith(1);
```